# eclipse sonar plugin with php language support

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube5.1, eclipse-mars

I have successfully installed sonar server and sonarqube eclipse plugin.  As Sonar eclipse plug-in is not supporting PHP language. I am not able to use this plug-in. 
SonarQube team has any plan of launching eclipse plug-in with language support soon?